# Firing click event from code in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have created a custom widget in gwt which extends the composite.I am using focus panel in that.For FocusPanel I added ClickHandler.Then I have added keyboard listner.Now on press of Enter key it should trigger click event.Can any one help me to trigger click event by using code in GWT?

```
focusPanel.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)        {
                    // TODO call onClick() method
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't done this for a click event, but I've done change events like this.

```
NativeEvent event = Document.get().createChangeEvent();
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event, this);
```

The [`createClickEvent`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createClickEvent(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean)) method takes a lot more parameters though.

```
public final NativeEvent createClickEvent(int detail,
                                          int screenX,
                                          int screenY,
                                          int clientX,
                                          int clientY,
                                          boolean ctrlKey,
                                          boolean altKey,
                                          boolean shiftKey,
                                          boolean metaKey)
```

Answer (score 21):

I have done this code:

```
if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)        {
    myButton.fireEvent( new GwtEvent<ClickHandler>() {
        @Override
        public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<ClickHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return ClickEvent.getType();
        }
        @Override
        protected void dispatch(ClickHandler handler) {
            handler.onClick(null);
        }
   });
}
```

Of course myButton must be final or public cause you are inside another event handler.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer as it does the job. However, this is a lot of boiler plate code for a small effect. Hopefully, one day Google will include that directly in GWT test automation.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use a simple JSNI method to do it.  Just pass your element [e.g. button.getElement()] to this method:

```
public static native void clickElement(Element elem) /*-{
    elem.click();
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 4):

If the target is a button you can just call its `click()` method. Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
private void click(HasHandlers handlerSource) {
  NativeEvent event = Document.get().createClickEvent(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false);
  DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event, handlerSource);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method described by DLH should work and except for the detail argument (which I have no idea what's it for) you have the other arguments available in the KeyPressEvent.

Another possible solution is to call the native JavaScript `click()` on the element. I've done this in a Button widget (Which is available as open source). See `click()` method in the following class: http://code.google.com/p/cobogw/source/browse/trunk/widgets/src/main/java/org/cobogw/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.java), which calls a specific Event2 class, that implements the browser specific versions of the click method.

To use this method, you could simply add the jar file provided with [cobogw](http://www.cobogw.org) to your project, include the `Event.gwt.xml` and call `Event2.fireClickEvent(getElement());` in your method or only use the code from the classes Event2 and Event in your own project

This solution also allows you the programmatically fire a click event.

Also take a look at the `onBrowserEvent` implementation in the Button class mentioned above , since it handles the key event in a similar way you want, and works around the problem of the firing of multiple key events, when you only want to generate 1 click event.

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that the KeyPressHandler doesn't work in Firefox for special keys like ENTER, you would need to use the KeyUp or KeyDown

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5558#c6

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Maybe [ClickListenerCollection.fireClick()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ClickListenerCollection.html#fireClick%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) does what you want. I haven't used it though</strike>

Sorry, that is deprecated and maybe not even useful. I guess you shoul look at widget.delegateEvent instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
focusPanel.fireEvent(new ClickEvent(){});
```

Comment: 'ClickEvent()' has protected access in 'com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent'

Comment: @GlenPierce Correct, but you're not calling its protected constructor, you are creating a new anonymous inner class, and using its constructor.  Try the code, you'll see it compiles fine.