# GWT - How to set Initial condition for Window ResizeHandler

Tags: java, gwt

I think Window.addResizeHandler is a last resort to resize widgets according to the size of the browser window. And I have come to that last resort.

So, I have onResize sizing up my widgets beautifully, except when the application starts up.

How do I trigger at startup of the app, such a widget resize calculation done by onResize?

I cannot/should not tell users to use the mouse to deliberately resize the browser so as to trigger optimal widget distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question. The answer is ...

on module load, use Window.getClientWidth/Height and apply the width/height to the resize routine used by the resize handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add this call after your widget has been initialized or set visible:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
       //Resize code here
        }
    });
}
```

Note : You don't have to trigger the resize event by using this approach, but just set the size that you want on the widget. You can also go by triggering the event in the execute method if this approach is easier for you. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238355/firing-click-event-from-code-in-gwt) for firing events manually.

Comment: Nope ... not about when to trigger resize, but about how to get the window size. How to detect window size at startup.

Comment: And the answer is ... Window.getClientWidth/Height.

Comment: So glad you found your way... I think there are some start-up tutorials out there....