# GWT: Opening new mail window without browser tab opened

Tags: gwt, mailto

I am trying to open an email client just like using `<a href="mailto:john.doe@mail.com">mail me</a>` tag.

But I want to use my custom widget, which is not hyperlink, anchor or so. I added a DOM handler to my widget to listen to clicks:

```
public class VContactWidget extends VHorizontalLayout implements ClickHandler {

private HandlerRegistration clickHandler;

public VContactWidget() {
    // added some content here
    clickHandler = addDomHandler(this, ClickEvent.getType());
}

@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.open("mailto:john.doe@mail.com", "_blank", "");
}

}
```

Everything is working fine except one detail: When the widget is clicked, new empty browser tab will open with url set to `mailto:john.doe@mail.com`. I don't want the new tab opened. Can I avoid it somehow?

Note I set `_blank` parameter, as used in many examples. I also tried to use empty string or some other values as well. I looked into documentation, but didn't find anything useful.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

One solution may be to use Anchor, but my component is more complex, not just single `<a>` link.

Another detail to note may be application server - I am using Tomcat 7 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to fire native event on hidden Anchor programatically did not work for me. (Which does not mean it cannot be done.)

This is, how I actually solved my problem: Instead of `Window.open()`, I used following call:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.Location.assign("mailto:john.doe@mail.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can control. Whether this link opens in a new tab or a new window depends on the browser settings and user preferences.

I don't think it will make a difference if you use an Anchor or Window.open. In either case, the behavior may be different in different browsers. Also remember that for some users a click on this link will open Outlook or Mail, while for other users it will open Gmail in a browser window.

UPDATE:

If you want an exact behavior of an `<a>` element, create a hidden anchor element and fire a click on it when a user clicks on your composite widget.

[Firing click event from code in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238355/firing-click-event-from-code-in-gwt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Andrei.

If I use directly the code <a href="mailto:john.doe@mail.com">mail me</a> in static html page, no new tab is opened. (at least in Chrome) Which is what I want. I would expect, that using Anchor, which generates exact same code, will behave in same way. (No, I did not try it, because I cannot use Anchor anyways.) It does not look like it is dependent just on browser settings.

Comment: It also depends on a default email client. For many users a click on this link will open Outlook or Mail, while for other users it will open Gmail, etc.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort, Andrei. However, I was not able to fire native event on hidden Anchor programmatically. I found another solution, see my own Answer. Cheers!